# node js adding node or element to xml file

Tags: node.js, xml, dom, cheerio

How can I add new node/element or update xml file in node js express?
I try to do it with cheerio, my code:

```
$ = cheerio.load("my.xml", {xmlMode: true});    
$('urlset').append('<url><loc>www.google.com</loc></url>');
```

Comment: Can you just format the whole `XML` file into `JSON`, and then add the data you want, and once is done, just format the `JSON`back to `XML`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, if you have some example how to convert xml to json it will help me, thanks

Comment: I posted the answer below, I hope that will help you

Answer (score 2):

You just format the whole XML file into JSON, and then add the data you want, and once is done, just format the JSON to XML

```
const js2xmlparser = require('js2xmlparser');
const xml2js = require('xml2js').parseString;

// Rading your XML file
const origin  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <root> <name>Felix</name> </root>';
// Making a JSON object so you can edit it easily
xml2js(origin, (error, editableJSON) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        editableJSON.stackOverflow = true;
        // Making it back to XML
        const resultXML = js2xmlparser.parse('root', editableJSON);
        console.log(resultXML)
    }
});
```

Demo
https://runkit.com/moongod101/598bd24d5a737100125cb948